# Angular select does not filter my ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm using select field to filter my content as shown below:

```
           <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 ticket-status">Ticket Status:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4" ng-controller="LookupController as lookupCtrl" ng-init="getTicketStatusList()">
                        <select ng-options="t.Name for t in ticketstatus track by t.Id" ng-model="statusFilter" class="form-control"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="list-ticket" ng-repeat="ticket in myticket | filter : {Status: statusFilter}: true">
                <a href="/ticket/info/{{ticket.Id}}">
                    <ul class="list-inline ticket-list">
                        <li>
                            <i class="fa fa-ticket fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="ticket-title">#{{ticket.TicketNo}}: {{ticket.Title}}</p>
                            <p>{{ticket.Category}}</p>
                            <p>{{ticket.Priority}}</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </div>
```

The thing is, the list doesn't get updated when I change the selection on the select field. Can someone please tell me what I've done wrong? If the select field is not generated using angular, this filter works fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `select` filter is in `LookupController`, so it would have it's own scope so the filter won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `filter` and `ngRepeat` are not in the same `Controller`; therefore the `$scope` is different (as @user2718281's comment above). Try using the same `Controller` for both of them (place it on the their parent `<div>`). So, it would be something like:

```
<div class="parent-container" ng-controller="LookupController as lookupCtrl">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
        <!--Filter term here-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-ticket" ng-repeat="ticket in myticket | filter : {Status: statusFilter}: true">
        <!--ngRepeat here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: It works, Darren! Thanks to you now I understand more about the Controller's ability.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

```
<select ng-options="t.Status as t.Name for t in ticketstatus track by t.Id" ng-model="statusFilter" class="form-control"></select>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.